# Having trouble paraphrasing sentence

Tags: logic

F: French wins gold medal

G: Germans win gold medal

D: Danish win gold medal

I have to use truth connectives to paraphrase:

They will not all win gold medals

I am thinking when paraphrasing it ,
one country can win and two loose or
Two win and one loose

Am I on the right path?

Comment: Or all three of them could lose.

Comment: So altogether 3 exclusive paraphrases

Answer (score 1):

You can parse "Not all win golds medals" as "At least one does not win a gold medal." Either way, you can parse as:

~(F & G & D)

Which is truth-functionally equivalent to:

(~F v ~G v ~D)

Both are consistent with all three losing, two losing and one winning, or one losing and two winning.

Comment: Thanks for helping

Comment: Happy to do so, and happy to do more if you've any other questions.